# Trying to create text boxes dynammically and remove them

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I am using VB.NET <strike>vb 2008</strike> . I am trying to create text boxes dynammically and remove them here is the code i have written so far

```
 Private Sub setTextBox()
        Dim num As Integer
        Dim pos As Integer

        num = Len(word)
        temp = String.Copy(word)
        Dim intcount As Integer





        remove()
        GuessBox.Visible = True
        letters.Visible = True



        pos = 0
        'To create the dynamic text box and add the controls 
        For intcount = 0 To num - 1
            Txtdynamic = New TextBox
            Txtdynamic.Width = 20
            Txtdynamic.Visible = True
            Txtdynamic.MaxLength = 1
            Txtdynamic.Location = New Point(pos + 5, 0)
            pos = pos + 30
            'set the font size
            Txtdynamic.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
            Txtdynamic.Name = "txtdynamic_" & intcount & "_mycntrl"
            Txtdynamic.Enabled = False
            Txtdynamic.Text = ""

            Panel1.Controls.Add(Txtdynamic)

        Next
        Panel1.Visible = True
        Controls.Add(Panel1)
        Controls.Add(GuessBox)
        Controls.Add(letters)
        letter = ""
        letters.Text = ""
        hang_lable.Text = ""

        tries = 0
    End Sub`enter code here`  



 Function remove()


            For Each ctrl In Panel1.Controls

            Panel1.Controls.Remove(ctrl)

        Next
    End Function
```

I am able to create the textboxes but only a few of them are removed. by using  For Each ctrl In Panel1.Controls it doesn't retrieve all the controls and some ae duplicated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change your remove to

```
Sub remove()
    For i As Integer = Panel1.Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Panel1.Controls.Remove(Panel1.Controls(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

If I am not mistaken you should not change a collection in a loop that you are currently looping, using a for each. The safest ways would be to use the index, in reverse, so that the position is not affected.